# Find exact string and replace with carriage return plus string with visual studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am looking to find all instances of the exact string `"Public"` and replace it with `" ' \n Public"` (Add an empty comment above every Public declaration. )

I would also like to ignore any lines that are already commented out i.e. 'Public, and capture the whole line

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 works with Regex, Find=Public, Replace=\nPublic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is

1. Load up the **Find and Replace** dialog and put **Public** in the *Find what* field and put **'\nPublic** in the *Replace with* field.
2. Check *Match case* and *Use Regular Expressions*

And away you go. The extension [Multiline Search and Replace](http://ps://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PeterMacej.MultilineSearchandReplace) makes this a bit easier.

If you want normalized Windows-style line endings, you may want to replace with **'\r\nPublic** instead.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2019 will allow you to replace `Public` with `'\nPublic` when using RegEx option. However if you don't have 2019 (or it doesn't work for some other reason), you can write some code to do it:

Put this method in your code and start debugging, then call the method

```
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

    Public Sub foo()
        Dim fileName = New System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(True).GetFrame(0).GetFileName()
        Dim fileContents As String
        Using sr = New StreamReader(fileName)
            fileContents = sr.ReadToEnd().Replace(
                "Pub" & "lic",
                "'" & Environment.NewLine & "Pub" & "lic") ' String split so not replaced
        End Using
        Using sw = New StreamWriter(fileName, False)
            sw.Write(fileContents)
        End Using
    End Sub

    Sub Main()
        foo()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it's not natively possible with Visual Studio, but you can download a plugin like

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PeterMacej.MultilineSearchandReplace,

that provides such support.